# Why I'm getting errors of a PHP file while I am accessing another PHP file?

Tags: php

I have a problem in my php script. The problem is in loginpage.php. I have addcategory.php and it runs fine with no error. But, whenever i try to access loginpage.php, it shows the url of loginpage.php but throws error message in error.log file related to addcategory.php. The message is like:

```
PHP Warning:  include(../session.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/RamroDeal/php/controller/admin/addcategory.php on line 2

PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '../session.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/RamroDeal/php/controller/admin/addcategory.php on line 2

PHP Warning:  include(../../view/fns.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/RamroDeal/php/controller/admin/addcategory.php on line 3

PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '../../view/fns.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/RamroDeal/php/controller/admin/addcategory.php on line 3
```

and There was another error message before these above error messages. It's as follow

```
Cannot redeclare __autoload() (previously declared in /var/www/RamroDeal/php/controller/loginpage.php:5) in /var/www/RamroDeal/php/controller/admin/addCategory.php on line 8, referer: http://localhost/RamroDeal/php/index.php
```

I don't understand why it is accessing addcategory.php when i'm requesting for loginpage.php. Please help!!!

The php page are given below

loginpage.php

```
session_start();
include '../view/fns.php';

spl_autoload_register(function ($obj)
{
    $class = strtolower($obj);
    include '../class/'.$class.'.php';
});

$msg = '';
if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['pw']))
{
    $filter = Validation::getValidationInstance();
    $email = $filter->filter($_POST['email']);
    $pw = $filter->filter($_POST['pw']);

    $login = Log::getLogInstance();

    $login->setProperty($email, $pw, Database::getDBInstance());

    $msg = $login->login();
}

//Displaying heading part of html
ramrodeal_header("Login - RamroDeal - Great Deal, Great Price");

//Displaying navigation part of html
nav();

if (empty($_SESSION['email']))
{
    //Displaying login form
    login_form();
    echo $msg;
} else{
    switch($_SESSION['type']){
        case 'administrator':
            $home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/admin/adminHomepage.php';
            header('Location: ' . $home_url);('Location: ' . $home_url);
            break;

        case 'sub-administrator':
            $home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/admin/subAdminHomepage.php';
            header('Location: ' . $home_url);('Location: ' . $home_url);
            break;

        case 'merchant':
            $home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/merchant/merchantHomepage.php';
            header('Location: ' . $home_url);('Location: ' . $home_url);
            break;

        case 'agent':
            $home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/agent/agentHomepage.php';
            header('Location: ' . $home_url);('Location: ' . $home_url);
            break;

        default:
            $home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/customer/customerHomepage.php';
            header('Location: ' . $home_url);('Location: ' . $home_url);
    }
}

//Displaying footer of html
ramrodeal_footer();
```

addcategory.php

```
include('../session.php');
include('../../view/fns.php');

spl_autoload_register(function ($obj)
{
    $class = strtolower($obj);
    include '../../class/'.$class.'.php';
});


//Displaying heading part of html
ramrodeal_header("RamroDeal - Great Deal, Great Price");

//Displaying navigation part of html
nav();

//displaying add category form
addCategory();

$dealcategory = Category::getCategoryInstance(Database::getDBInstance());

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $filter = Validation::getValidationInstance();
    $name = $filter->filter($_POST['name']);

    $dealcategory->setProperty($name);
    $msg = $dealcategory->addCategory();
    echo $msg;
}

$deallist = $dealcategory->getCategory();

categoryTable($deallist);

//Displaying footer of html
ramrodeal_footer();
```

**UPDATE:**

Both pages have different directory structure

loginpage.php is in var/www/myapp/php/controller/

addcategory.php is in var/www/myapp/php/controller/admin/

Comment: Maybe a rewrite rule on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `view/fns.php`, why it include `addcategory.php`?

Comment: session.php is in var/www/myapp/php/controller

Comment: And where your file `loginpage.php`?

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have placed only one autoload function in one page. loginpage.php and addcategory.php are two different script and i haven't linked these two page. My question is why i'm getting addcategory.php errors while accessing loginpage.php

Comment: loginpage.php is in var/www/myapp/php/controller/

Comment: addcategory.php is in var/www/myapp/php/controller/admin/

Comment: Ok, try in addcategory.php in first line type: `throw new Exception();` - You will see path of stack - checke where addcategory.php has been included in loginpage.php

Comment: Just run in browser - and see where - you will check, and understand why in loginpage.php include addcategory.php

Comment: Uncaught exception 'Exception' in /var/www/myapp/php/controller/admin/addcategory.php:2\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/myapp/php/view/fns.php(7): include()\n#1 /var/www/myapp/php/controller/loginpage.php(3): include_once('/var/www/RamroD...')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/myapp/php/controller/admin/addcategory.php on line 2

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' in /var/www/myapp/php/controller/admin/addcategory.php:2\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/myapp/php/view/fns.php(7): include()\n#1 /var/www/myapp/php/controller/loginpage.php(3): include_once('/var/www/myapp...')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/myapp/php/controller/admin/addcategory.php on line 2

Comment: Ok, whell why in fns.php included addcategory.php?

Comment: actually fns.php lies in var/www/myapp/php/view/ and the one addcategory.php included is the html view code placed in var/www/myapp/php/view/admin/ for addcategory.php of var/www/myapp/php/controller/admin/ i think it's due to collision of script name

Comment: Please, choose my answer :)

Comment: here we go ;) @Sergey